# Manipulate iterated CSV files in For Loop R

Tags: r, for-loop

thank you for the help! Here is a description of what I am doing.

I have a classification problem where I need to classify athletic movements according to the csv file filled with sensor data.

The main training set looks like this:

```
    > head(main_train)
    Subject                            Datafile                   Label
1 Subject02 Subject02/Subject02_Aufnahme000.csv         curve-left-step
2 Subject02 Subject02/Subject02_Aufnahme001.csv         curve-left-step
3 Subject02 Subject02/Subject02_Aufnahme002.csv            stand-to-sit
4 Subject02 Subject02/Subject02_Aufnahme003.csv curve-right-spin-Rfirst
5 Subject02 Subject02/Subject02_Aufnahme004.csv            jump-one-leg
6 Subject02 Subject02/Subject02_Aufnahme005.csv   lateral-shuffle-right
```

I have managed to iterate through these files like so:

```
csv <- list.files(path = "Subjects/Subject02/", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
```

I would like to first split the dataset into quarters, extract the mean, median, sd, max, and min from each column of the quarters, and get one row with mean_1, mean_2, mean_3, mean,_4...

Then, I can insert the new row data in place of the Datafile value (which isn't a problem once I can get the above mentioned.

I am using For loops, but I tried *EVERYTHING* (lapply, sapply, but of those with functions between, ...) . My result should return 440 rows for the number of csv files, but, on this version I am only getting one row back. I would loove some help on this. Plus, I think it is an interesting dilemma that should be relatable to other loop issues.

Here is my code:

```
for(i in csv) { 
  dataset <- read.csv(i)

  first = round(nrow(dataset)/4)
  second = 2 * round(nrow(dataset)/4)
  third = 3 * round(nrow(dataset)/4)

  dataset_1 = dataset[1:first,]
  dataset_2 = dataset[first:second,]
  dataset_3 = dataset[second:third,]
  dataset_4 = dataset[third:nrow(dataset),]

  for (v in dataset_1){
    mean_1 = mean(v)
    median_1 = median(v)
    sd_1 = sd(v)
    min_1 = min(v)
    max_1 = max(v)
  }
  for (v in dataset_2){
    mean_2 = mean(v)
    median_2 = median(v)
    sd_2 = sd(v)
    min_2 = min(v)
    max_2 = max(v)
  }
  for (v in dataset_3){
    mean_3 = mean(v)
    median_3 = median(v)
    sd_3 = sd(v)
    min_3 = min(v)
    max_3 = max(v)
  }
  for (v in dataset_1){
    mean_4 = mean(v)
    median_4 = median(v)
    sd_4 = sd(v)
    min_4 = min(v)
    max_4 = max(v)
  }

  subject_data <- cbind(mean_1, mean_2, mean_3, mean_4,
                        median_1, median_2, median_3, median_4,
                        sd_1, sd_2, sd_3, sd_4,
                        min_1, min_2, min_3, min_4,
                        max_1, max_2, max_3, max_4)
}
```

and the result, which is only one row, and needs to be 440:

```
    > subject_data
       mean_1   mean_2   mean_3   mean_4 median_1 median_2 median_3 median_4     sd_1     sd_2     sd_3     sd_4 min_1 min_2
[1,] 33280.73 36429.69 35986.18 33280.73    33709    36904    35264    33709 1957.654 1797.988 4484.521 1957.654 29328 32184
     min_3 min_4 max_1 max_2 max_3 max_4
[1,] 22768 29328 38320 38320 46456 38320
```

Comment: I think this is a job which is best handled using purrr - Are you familiar with this package?

Comment: I am not familiar and haven't used it, but I've seen it mentioned in some related questions, and will definitely try to implement it now. Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. Did it also solve your issue with the number of rows?

Comment: @SteenHarsted I think that there is a major problem with RStudio and copying and pasting. I ended up literally retyping everything word for word and it worked. Not sure why, and a lot of hours spent messing around. But the code ended up working in that sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with motion data myself and I suggest a different structure of your data. I really think this will make future data analysis easier for you.

As for your number of rows - I think this code will make it easier to pinpoint any potential errors in your data.

First I construct some data to mimic your structure. I create just three .csv files.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(here)

#Create some csv files
curve_left_step = rnorm(16, 0, 1)
stand_to_sit = rnorm(16, 20, 2)
jump_one_leg = rnorm(16, 15, 1)

write.csv(curve_left_step, here("Subject02_Aufnahme000.csv"))
write.csv(stand_to_sit, here("Subject02_Aufnahme002.csv"))
write.csv(jump_one_leg, here("Subject02_Aufnahme004.csv"))
```

I import these files into R using purrr. This keeps all the data in one dataframe. I also add a label column.

```
#Import the csv files into R using purrr
data_all <- tibble(
  path = list.files(path = here(), pattern = "Subject", full.names = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(
    data = map(.x=path, ~read.csv(file = .x)),
    label = c("curve_left_step", "stand_to_sit", "jump_one_leg"))
```

The strength of this data structure is that you can apply functions to the small datasets (the data column) within the data_all object.

First, we create such a function:

```
#Create a function that splits the data into 4 and keeps a selected quarter
split_and_calc <- function(.data, ...){
  .data %>%
    #Divide into quarters
    mutate(
      quarter = ceiling(row_number()/4)) %>% 
    #Select the quarter of interest  
    filter(quarter == ...) %>%
    #Select the variable of interest. here it is [[2]], but in your data this is likely different
    select(2) %>% 
    summarise_all(.funs = c("mean", "median", "sd", "min", "max"))
}
```

Now we apply the function to all the small dataframes in the data column:

```
#Apply the function to all dataframes in data column in data_all
data_all <- data_all %>% 
  mutate(
    quarter1 = map(.x=data, ~split_and_calc(.x, 1)),
    quarter2 = map(.x=data, ~split_and_calc(.x, 2)),
    quarter3 = map(.x=data, ~split_and_calc(.x, 3)),
    quarter4 = map(.x=data, ~split_and_calc(.x, 4)))


> data_all
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  path                                                          data               label         quarter1           quarter2          quarter3          quarter4         
  <chr>                                                         <list>             <chr>         <list>             <list>            <list>            <list>           
1 C:/Users/sharsted/OneDrive/R/R club/Facebook help/Subject02_~ <data.frame [16 x~ curve_left_s~ <data.frame [1 x ~ <data.frame [1 x~ <data.frame [1 x~ <data.frame [1 x~
2 C:/Users/sharsted/OneDrive/R/R club/Facebook help/Subject02_~ <data.frame [16 x~ stand_to_sit  <data.frame [1 x ~ <data.frame [1 x~ <data.frame [1 x~ <data.frame [1 x~
3 C:/Users/sharsted/OneDrive/R/R club/Facebook help/Subject02_~ <data.frame [16 x~ jump_one_leg  <data.frame [1 x ~ <data.frame [1 x~ <data.frame [1 x~ <data.frame [1 x~
```

Your data from the individual .csv files are now stored in the data column, while Quarter1 contains mean, median, sd, min, and max for the 1 quarter of the data, and likewise for quarter2,3 and 4.

Say you now want to access your summary values from quarter1. You can do the following code:

```
data_all %>% 
  select(label, quarter1) %>% 
  unnest()
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  label              mean  median    sd    min    max
  <chr>             <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 curve_left_step  -0.360  -0.384 0.833  -1.13  0.458
2 stand_to_sit     20.9    21.0   2.09   18.9  22.8  
3 jump_one_leg     14.9    15.0   0.315  14.5  15.2
```

Comment: Hi @marc_s, what do you mean with "select the variable of interest" and "select(2)"?

Comment: Hi @MargiSant , That line selects a single column from the imported .csv file. This column is then used for calculating the descriptive stats you want. In the data I have created, the column of interest is the second one - therefore `select(2)`. I dont know your data structure in the csv file, but if you only have one column you can skip the select line.